# MySQL GROUP BY In DESC Order

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following 3 fields,

```
msg_id | conversation_id | subject
1 |   1 | 1st message
2 |   1 | 2nd message
```

I want to get last record of each conversation. so I write the below query,

```
SELECT max(msg_id) as msg_id,  `conversation_id` ,  `subject` 
FROM  `tbl_messages` 
GROUP BY  `conversation_id` 
ORDER BY  `msg_id` DESC
```

It gives me the `msg_id 2` but in `subject` it gives `1st message`

I get help from this question for the `max()`  [How to group by DESC order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390303/how-to-group-by-desc-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want information about the last message in each conversation, then the right query is one that joins this information together:

```
select m.*
from tbl_messages m join
     (select conversation_id, max(msg_id) max_msg_id
      from tbl_messages
      group by conversation_id
     ) mc
     on m.msg_id = mc.max_msg_id;
```

Comment: yes its working perfect now, can you please explain it little bit also. I dont understand whats the meaning of m.* and mc

Comment: @sHAmsuLaRiFeEn . . . Those are table aliases, a standard part of the SQL language.  They are just a shorter name for tables and subqueries in the `from` clause.

Comment: Surely one would also need `conversation_id` in the join predicate

Comment: @eggyal . . . I thought about that.  But then I figured that the column `msg_id` is probably the primary key for `tbl_messages`.  If so, you only need the match on that column.

Comment: Ah, good point!  I suppose it need not be in the derived table's select list then - I just glanced over and wondered what purpose it served there.