# Getting the recent row by JOIN & GROUP BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is table `album` and it's structure and data is,

[image]

This is another table `photos` and it's structure and data is,

[image]

I would like to list all the album name, total photos for that corresponding album, last uploaded image by JOIN and GROUP BY.

This is the Codeigniter query I'm using right now. Everything works except it fetches the first row of `image` column value instead of latest one.

```
 $query = $this->db->select('albums.name, photos.image, albums.created, albums.id, 
    COUNT(photos.id) as total')
   ->from('photos')
   ->join('albums', 'albums.id = photos.album_id')  
   ->order_by('photos.id', 'desc')
   ->group_by('photos.album_id')                       
   ->limit($limit, $offset)
   ->get();
```

The generated SQL query for above is,

```
SELECT `albums`.`name`, `photos`.`image`, `albums`.`created`, `albums`.`id`, COUNT(photos.id) as total FROM `photos` JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`id` = `photos`.`album_id` GROUP BY `photos`.`album_id` ORDER BY `photos`.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

For both the query the result is,

> [{"name":"Movie
>   Stills","image":"assets/images/albums/2016/01/84786b91857b45fa9391943e9a468ac6.jpg","created":"2016-01-19
>   23:41:53","id":"3","total":"3"},{"name":"Firstlook","image":"assets/images/albums/2016/01/6e90cdfdec444dfc53f4a7c30a2ac31e.jpg","created":"2016-01-19
>   23:16:05","id":"1","total":"2"}]

If you look the image key, it shows the value of first one instead of last row.

I'm open to any of both query solution (Codeigniter/SQL).

Comment: from albums table and join the photos table

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390303/how-to-group-by-desc-order

Comment: @K1N6 There column in integer type. Here, its alphanumeric. So, MAX doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many try, I got a solution to my problem. Here's the query which is simple,

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.`image`, COUNT(p.`id`) as total, a.`id`, a.`created`, a.`name` FROM `albums` as a JOIN (SELECT * FROM `photos` as p1 ORDER BY id DESC) p ON a.`id` = p.`album_id` GROUP BY p.`album_id` ORDER BY p.`id` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

I used sub query as said by @Shadow, and i just did ORDER BY for sub query's column `Id`. Through this, everything works as expected.

Comment: And when mysql silently changes how it behaves when you donot use full group by or the code is migrated to a mysql server where full group by is a requirement, then xou will be surprised why your code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping by `photos`.`album_id`, but the created date field is not subject to an agrregate function, therefore mysql picks up a random row's value according to the documentation (well, it's not that much random, it picks up the 1st corresponding value it encounters while scanning the data)

Use max() on the created date field to retrieve the latest date:

```
    SELECT max(`albums`.`name`) as name, `photos`.`image`, max(`albums`.`created`) as latest_date, `albums`.`id`, COUNT(photos.id) as total
FROM `photos` JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`id` = `photos`.`album_id`
GROUP BY `photos`.`album_id`
ORDER BY `photos`.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

You will have the same issues with `photos`.`image`. To get the image associated with the latest created date you will need a subquery.

```
select a.name, p.image, t.mdate
from albums a
inner join (select album_id, max(created_date) as mdate from photos group by album_id) t on a.id=t.album_id
inner join photos p on a.id=p.album_id and t.mdate=p.created_date
```

Comment: Thank you but my only concern is getting recent `image`. How can i achieve using sub query?

Comment: Empty result. BTW it is `created` not `created_date`. You need anything from me, I can give it out.

Comment: Provide me with the exact query you run. You may have mixed up the date columns in the join

Comment: Can you help?? I couldn;t get.

Comment: @Strawberry perhaps you could provide some pointers as to what's wrong with it. The only place for improvement I can see is to use max(photo.id) instead of max(created) to do the join on the subquery. However, as far as I can see even the current version should return the latest photo's details by album_id, provided the albums have at least 1 corresponding image.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh, <not too nice words about myself> - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->select('albums.name, ph.image, albums.created, albums.id, 
    COUNT(ph.id) as total')
                ->from('photos as ph') // added prefix
                ->join('albums', 'albums.id = ph.album_id')
                ->where('ph.id = (SELECT MAX(ph1.id) FROM photos as ph1 WHERE ph1.album_id=ph.album_id)',NULL,FALSE) // subquery to get latest record
                ->order_by('ph.id', 'desc')
                ->group_by('ph.album_id')
                ->limit($limit, $offset)
                ->get();
```

The NULL,FALSE in the where() tells `CodeIgniter` not to escape the query, which may mess it up [Sub query in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047554/3289108)

Alternatively, SQL Query is

```
SELECT `albums`.`name`, `ph`.`image`, `albums`.`created`, `albums`.`id`, COUNT(ph.id) as total FROM `photos` as `ph` JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`id` = `ph`.`album_id` WHERE ph.id IN (SELECT MAX(ph1.id) FROM photos as ph1 WHERE ph1.album_id=ph.album_id) GROUP BY `ph`.`album_id` ORDER BY `ph`.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `ph1 WHERE ph1`.`album_id=ph`.`album_id`) GROUP BY `ph`.`album_id` ORDER BY `' at line 4`

Comment: BTW I mainly need to get latest `image` value.

Comment: Thanks to your query. I just need to add some extra parameter in `WHERE` condition to work.

Comment: @user3289108 Welcome, I have run my query and it was working fine though. Glad if i could have help you!

Comment: Checkout my edits in your answer. May be Codeigniter V3 has a strict condition.

Comment: You are running a subquery for each of the image records. This is not too effective!

Comment: But, the total is not working well. It shows `1` for all result :(

Comment: @Shadow Right! I couldn't get the current total value. It shows Subquery returns more than one row.