# MySQL - Using desc on Group by

Tags: mysql

I have this query and I would like to use an order by desc on the avg :

```
select Nomcircuit, avg(Monuments.NBETOILE) as TotalEtoiles from Circuits      
inner join CircuitsMonuments on Circuits.Idcircuit = CircuitsMonuments.Idcircuit
inner join Monuments on Monuments.Idmonument = CircuitsMonuments.Idmonument
group by Nomcircuit;
```

I've tried several things but it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What "several things" have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by DESC order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390303/how-to-group-by-desc-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as you suggested:

```
SELECT Nomcircuit,
       AVG(Monuments.NBETOILE) AS TotalEtoiles
FROM Circuits      
INNER JOIN CircuitsMonuments
    ON Circuits.Idcircuit = CircuitsMonuments.Idcircuit
INNER JOIN Monuments
    ON Monuments.Idmonument = CircuitsMonuments.Idmonument
GROUP BY Nomcircuit
ORDER BY TotalEtoiles DESC
```